# how to check all words then append to a list - python

Tags: python

I've three lists, one is `black list` of words and one is `frequency` and the other `new words` i want to check if one of `new_words` words in black list then append 1 to `frequency` if not append 0 to `frequency`, but i want to after all words been checked,
**i have to check all words in the speech then if one of the words inside the black list then just append once not for the entire for loop**
here is what im trying :

```
frequency = []
the_speech = 'hello how are you, what a shit you said'
list_of_speech = the_speech.split(' ')
print(list_of_speech)
black_lists = ['fuck', 'shit'] #more and more
for s in list_of_speech:            
    if s in black_lists:
        frequency.append(1)
        print('inserted into black list')
        break
    else:
        frequency.append(0)
        print('inserted, wihtout finding a black list word')
        break
```

but this doesnt work as i expect, it always decide base one the first element of the list, how to make it complete the all loop then do the append, thank you in advance ..

Comment: can you explain why are you trying to do it ?
You want to create the whole frequency list after the loop ends ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll give it another shot. Here you loop through the list and check everytime for a bad word. If you find one bad word you break out the loop. after that you check if `no_bad_word` is True/False and print a final statement.

```
the_speech = 'hello how are you, what a shit you said'
list_of_speech = the_speech.split(' ')
print(list_of_speech)
black_lists = ['fuck', 'shit'] #more and more
no_bad_word = True
for s in list_of_speech:            
    if s in black_lists:
        print('User had a bad word in his speech')
        no_bad_word = False
        break

if no_bad_word:
    print('the speech has no bad words of the black list')
```

EDIT:
I have another way for you with `any()` :
it checks the list on the black_list and in the end, if there is only once `True` then there was a bad word in it.

```
decision = any(word.lower() in black_lists for word in list_of_speech)
if decision:
    print('User had a bad word in his speech')
else:
    print('the speech has no bad words of the black list')
```

Comment: The second is the way optimal way to do it, in my opinion. One suggestion: compare `word.lower()` instead of `word`.

Comment: If you like my answer please accept it as the right answer. As @CrazyChucky pointed out, I also think, the second way is the best solution here.

Comment: @CrazyChucky just edited my answer to your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you use break at every end of statements, which will make it run one time.

**Method 1:** (Original)

Just remove the break and it should work. But this can be easily bypassed by using a `.` after it or using uppercase.

**UPDATED:**

- Removed useless thing

```py
contain_bad_word = False
the_speech = 'hello how are you, what a shit you said'
list_of_speech = the_speech.split(' ')
print(list_of_speech)
black_lists = ['fuck', 'shit'] #more and more
for s in list_of_speech:            
    if s in black_lists:
        contain_bad_word = True
        print('blah blah')
        break
```

**Method 2:** (more accurate, recommend)

Rabinzel question is the same (I updated after him/her so I wann put in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71363926/18298515))
This method will loop though the black listed and check is there any in the string.

```
contain_bad_word = False
the_speech = 'hello how are you, what a shit you said'
list_of_speech = the_speech.split(' ')
print(list_of_speech)
black_lists = ['fuck', 'shit'] #more and more
for s in black_lists:            
    if s.upper() in the_speech.upper(): #No uppercase bypass
        contain_bad_word = True
        print('blah blah')
        break
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it will continue printing appending till find a word, i wanto after checks all words the append

Comment: @HunarMohammed Hi, I don't very understand that. Do you want to make it after checking, it will add 1 if there are bad words and 0 when none?

Comment: yes, i want to append after the loop complets

Comment: i want to append after the for loop completes, and append once, not for the entire list

Comment: @HunarMohammed It's unclear what you want. What should the final frequency list look like?

Comment: this is just not possible. you loop through a list and compare it to the blacklists. you MUST save the information somewhere, or how do you know after completing the loop what to append in total? .....and if you save anything in any format during the loop, you can just append it directly. If we still don't understand what you want, please try to make your question more clear and in detail

Comment: @Rabinzel read the question again, i add more information about what i want to acheive

Comment: @CrazyChucky i want to check every statement from client if in his/her answer writes something bad, for the entire statement then decide

Comment: @HunarMohammed Do you want to after checked all words, print the thing you want if there are bad word?

Comment: ok, so all you need is the information if there was 1 or more bad words, right? Then why do you need a list with 0 and 1's ? You could for example make a counter, loop through the list and if there is a bad word, counter+=1. at the end you can print a statement in an if/else dependent on the number of the counter.

Comment: @BrainFlooder yes, thats all

Comment: @Rabinzel yes, i looked for a better approach, just doing it into the for loop, but it seems there are no another way

Comment: @HunarMohammed If you want to check is there a bad word in a string there are more ways to do it.

Comment: @BrainFlooder for example ?

Comment: @HunarMohammed  I offered you another answer. see below.

Comment: @HunarMohammed added example

Comment: @BrainFlooder this is just what I posted 10 minutes ago

Comment: @Rabinzel I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Rabinzel I have added link to your answer in method 2.

Comment: ha wouldn't be necessary, but thanks! you put also a lot of effort in this discussion! Check your answer again, I think you deleted some wrong lines while editing.

Answer (score -1):

you can just do a double for loop like this

```
frequency = []
the_speech = 'hello how are you, what a shit you said'
list_of_speech = the_speech.split(' ')
print(list_of_speech)
black_lists = ['fuck', 'shit'] #more and more
for cword in list_of_speech:
    for blw in black_lists:
        if cword == blw:
            frequency.append(1)
            print("You have a blacklisted word")
        else:
            frequency.append(0)
```

and then you can add it to your list

Comment: that is not what the OP asked for

Comment: he said to check if it has a blacklisted word; add 1 to the frequancy else, add 0

Comment: but in your answer `frequency` list isn't filled at all.... and you loop through black_lists in every step which isn't needed

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this is even wrong, because you append 1 or 0 in every step in your two for loops and the result is a list double the length of the original list. OP only wants to append 1 or 0 in every step of the loop through the list `the_speech`